# Updating/Modifying a variable inside a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm trying to modify a variable inside of a function. But while I can print out the variable (so access it) I cant seem to modify it.

Is there a simple solution for this or am I doing it all wrong?

Code:

```
a_number = 500

def a_function():
    print(a_number)
    a_number -= 100
    print(a_number)

a_function()
```

I want to be able to have the function lower the value of "a_number" with 100.
But it gives me this error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a_number' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `global` key in you `a_function`.

```
a_number = 500

def a_function():
    global a_number
    print(a_number)
    a_number -= 100
    print(a_number)


a_function()
```

It tells the function to treat `a_number` as a `global` var instead that can be modified inside the function.

> In Python, `global` keyword allows you to modify the variable outside of the current scope. It is used to create a global variable and make changes to the variable in a local context.

Comment: wouldn't you want to declare it global outside of the function?

Comment: When you set a var outside a function it is by default declared as global. But in order to modify it inside a function, you need to add the `global` keyword.